# Watchkit upload invalid bundle

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit

From today (04/01) Watchkit Apps can be uploaded.
However I get the following message when uploading (also using application loader):

[image: Error-message]

Anybody else as well?

Comment: What is your minimum supported OS Version in the Info.plist?

Comment: There is none there, it was not created by xCode and also not selectable as an entry when I add a new key/value pair. I've tried adding a minimumOS key/value myself by simply typing it instead of selecting but that also didn't work..

Comment: So you already tried the key-value pair: "MinimumOSVersion" = "8.2" in the apple watch extension Info.plist file?

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using my very first Technical Support Request from Apple (after 5 years) it appears that it's a bug if you've created the WatchKit app using a beta version from Xcode. 
There are 2 solutions:
1. Use grep and terminal to find any instances of the string 8.1 or 8.3 in any files in your project. Then replace these with 8.2. 
2. Create a new extension with the newest non-beta Xcode.

Solution 1 worked perfectly for me! It appears that some Deployment Targets of some files are not visible in Xcode so grep was the only way to find these.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I solved it by changing **IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0;** to **IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.2;** in the project file (your_app.xcodeproj > project.pbxproj) where INFOPLIST_FILE = "your_app WatchKit Extension/Info.plist »;.